# Koethe  conjecture

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

First  of  all, has  the  Koethe  conjecture  been  solved ?! Does a proof of  the  following  statement  really  imply  the  proof  of  the  conjecture ?

- The sum of two right nil ideals in any ring is nil.

Are there  other  equivalent  statements  that  imply  the  conjecture ?

Thanks, SB

Comment: This seems to be a nice survey: http://www.math.bas.bg/serdica/2001/2001-159-170.pdf

Comment: Thanks  for  the  link ! As  a  matrix  fan, I also  found  the  following  statement http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=S3pZbAByfDgC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=K%C3%B6the+conjecture+ring++theory&source=bl&ots=8GcC1cmkW0&sig=n6N7Y3Je2hnRmsrVVxlx0V8F5XQ&hl=en&ei=Rq-cTq9mhLLyA9OPxZEJ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false  interesting :

- If  $I$ is  a  nil  ideal  in  $R$ then $M_n( I)$ is a nil  ideal  in $M_n(R)$ !

Comment: I'd never yet met a matrix fan :)

Comment: Oh yes I am  a big  fan  of  matrix  rings !:)

Answer (score 3):

Not solved. Many special cases though. The paper cited above looks nice, and another short survey is given in Lam's First Course in Noncommutative rings, around page 164. There are a bunch of equivalent statements there, but maybe the above paper covers them all.