# Koethe  conjecture  on  non associative  rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Following  up  on  [Koethe  conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78366/koethe-conjecture)  I  was  wondering  if  the  Koethe  conjecture  holds  for  non associative  rings. My  impression  is that, it  does  not hold.But  I am  not  sure ! Am  I  right ? Can  you  produce  a  counter  example ?

Cheers, Nick

Comment: It would seem appropriate to state the conjecture here.

Comment: Crosspost from math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73634/

Comment: You should definitely state what you are after. For example, what is "nil" for nonassociative rings?